# struct references compilation error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘&’ token

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct {int a; int b;} A_t;
A_t AA;
AA.a = 3; AA.b = 4;
// compilation fails here
A_t& BB = AA;
```

When trying to create a reference to an existing struct, I get the following compilation error:
"expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘&’ token"

What am I missing?

Comment: This is clearly C++, so remove the C tag. And compile with a C++ compiler

Comment: C and C++ are completely different languages. Choose one for a tag.

Comment: The C tag should stay, as the confusion between C and C++ is the root of the problem.

Comment: You cannot have `AA.a = 3;` outside of a function. Change to `A_t AA = { 3, 4};  A_t& BB = AA;`

Comment: Got it.  Thanks all.  FYI, this was to add functionality to the CAEN Digitizer sample and the I did not see that the makefile was using C instead of C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're compiling with a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler.

C has no notion of references, so declaring a variable like `A_t &BB` is invalid syntax.

If you're using references, you need to compile with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a C++ Program, then you could very well do

```
struct A_t{
int a;
int b;
};
A_t AA; // You don't need to preceed the struct name with the keyword struct
AA.a = 3;
AA.b = 4;
// your compilation failed in the below step
A_t& BB = AA; // Well, reference to variable (as in &BB) is a functionality of C++.
//If you get an error here, you're probably using a C compiler for a C++ pgm!
```